# Partial not found when attempting to render it from an Ajax call in Rails app

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, ajax

```
Rails 5.2.3
```

I have the following Ajax call:

```
function renderSalesDayDashboard(date_target) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "sales_day_dashboard",
    data: JSON.stringify({
      "date_target": date_target
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    remote: false,
    success: function(day_results) {
      try{
        $("#dayDashboard").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'sales/show/day_dashboard', locals: { day_results: @day_results } ) %>");
      }catch(e){
        alert(e)
      }
    }
  });
}
```

I verified that it's working, and that the @day_results variable is created at the controller.

I also verified that the partial:

```
sales/show/_day_dashboard.html.slim
```

exits, and I know it does, because this Ajax function re-renders it, but it initially renders as part of the sales/show.html.slim view.

I am, however, getting the error message:

```
Missing partial sales/show/_day_dashboard with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}
```

Any ideas?

## Edit:

Here's what sales/show/_day_dashboard.html.slim looks like for now:

```
#dayDashboard
  .panel.panel-default
    .panel-title
      = day_results.day
```

Here's the entire error message:

```
Showing ...../app/views/sales/show/_period_sales.html.erb where line #58 raised:

Missing partial sales/show/_day_dashboard.html with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:raw, :erb, :html, :builder, :ruby, :slim, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
  * "..../app/views"
  * "/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/devise-4.7.1/app/views"
  * "/Users/xxxx/.rbenv/versions/2.6.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/gems/kaminari-core-1.1.1/app/views"
```

Line 58 is:

```
$("#dayDashboard").html("<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'sales/show/day_dashboard', locals: { day_results: @day_results } ) %>");
```

Comment: You verified that the partial `sales/show/_day_dashboard` exists, but the error says the partial `devices/show/_day_dashboard` is missing. And, your js success function looks wonky.

Comment: Yes, it says it can't find it, but it's there

Comment: What does `app/views/devices/show/_day_dashboard.html.slim` look like?

Comment: See edit to my question. It's very simple for now, and all it does is display the say of the week.

Comment: Can you show the full error stack? your code referes to `sales/show` and the error to `devices/show`, the error seems to be somewhere else.

Comment: Sorry, I copied the wrong error response. I have a couple of partial views, and I'm testing them. I will edit my question

Comment: @arieljuod I edited the question with the full error stack

Comment: `partial ales/show/_day_dashboard.html` it says `ales` instead of `sales`, is that a typo, a copy paste error or do you have some reference to "ales" somewhere?

Comment: More like a copy/paste mishap. I was rushing out the door. There is no "ales: anywhere